# Extracting specific star data from Gaia DR2?

Tags: star, data-analysis, gaia

I would like to extract all Gaia DR2 sources which have six-parameter solutions as well as their radial velocities and effective temperatures. Is this possible as DR2 only specifies that there are 1,331,909,727 sources with parameters?

Comment: [my response](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/46892/query-gaia-by-star-name/46914#46914) here might help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this via [VizieR](https://vizier.u-strasbg.fr/viz-bin/VizieR) (main site at CDS, Strasbourg, France linked; worldwide mirrors are available). You can search by catalog name from that form or enter `I/345/gaia2` to get the specific catalog table we want. Assuming you have no other constraints other than what you specified in your question, we can enter the following into the constraint fields:

- Set **Solved** to `=31` (this says to only select sources with all 5 astrometric parameters fitted - see the "Note 14" link off to the side)
- Set **RV** to `!=` (this says to only return results with a non-null radial velocity)
- Set **fPriam** to `=100001` (this says to only return results from the astrophysical parameter estimation that are close to the stellar locus, have good colors and within the training sets for $T_{eff}$ and extinction. This is (unusually) not well documented or linked within VizieR; I looked this value up by experimenting and consulting [this table](https://gea.esac.esa.int/archive/documentation/GDR2/Data_analysis/chap_cu8par/sec_cu8par_data/ssec_cu8par_data_flags.html) in the Gaia-DR2 data documentation))

There may well be other constraints on fields that you will want to apply for your problem, particularly if you want well-measured sources and/or good parallaxes; you will need to consult the Gaia-DR2 release documentation. More info on how to apply constraints within VizieR is given by a pop-up help at the top of the form (where it says 'Query by constraints?' which links to [this page](https://vizier.u-strasbg.fr/vizier/vizHelp/cst.htx).

Finally, under Preferences along the left hand side, you will want to change the max number of rows to 'unlimited' and change the output format to something that will be directly download and not rendered by the browser (it crashed the tab in Firefox when I tried it with the default HTML table and unlimited results). Using a FITS binary table, I got a 1.1GB FITS table with 5,797,861 rows when I did this. You may want to look at using `cdsclient` (linked at the top of the query form) or other programmatic solutions e.g.  Astropy's [Astroquery for Vizier](https://astroquery.readthedocs.io/en/latest/vizier/vizier.html) if you are doing this regularly and are comfortable with some programming.

Comment: Is there a way for me to get a CSV file for direct download? I'm unfamiliar with VizieR tools, unfortunately.

Comment: Strangely comma-separated values don't seem to be possible but you can have Tab, pipe (`|`) or semicolon (`;`) separated format files downloaded. To do this, you can choose a different format under the drop-down menu under Preferences on the left hand side.

Comment: The reason why I'm asking this is because of some issues with importing the TSV to Excel. I tried it with 10 sources and it did not display properly. If there is any way to import to Excel, that would be great.

Comment: I don't have Excel itself (note Excel has a limit at a little over 1 million rows (2^20)) but a 1000 limit table in |-separated format imported just fine into LibreOffice Calc (1st column is extra wide because of the header but that's not the end of the world).  Screenshot (hopefully) here: https://imgur.com/a/qUI4R91